# Articoli indeterminativi per termini epicèni

Tags: articles, gender

Nelle parole che non si declinano per genere (anche se in questo caso si potrebbe), va usato l'articolo indeterminativo in base al genere del soggetto?

Esempio:

> La madre era un avvocato famoso (maschile)

oppure:

> La madre era un'avvocato famoso (femminile)

Comment: A parte che, come dici tu stesso, l'esempio è un po' infelice perché esiste sia “avvocata” che il deprecato “avvocatessa”, se un nome è grammaticalmente maschile, è maschile. Lo confermi implicitamente tu stesso usando in entrambi i casi l'aggettivo maschile. Prova un altro esempio: “Ci fu una rissa e chiamarono una guardia”. Diresti “e chiamarono un guardia” nel caso che la guardia accorsa fosse stata di sesso maschile?

Comment: Vedi [questo articolo](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/articoli/scritto_e_parlato/Errata_Corrige2.html): «Tuttavia l’incertezza (dovuta a motivi diversi, di ordine sociale, culturale e psicologico) ha determinato una terza formazione, grammaticalmente inaccettabile ma non scartata da molti italofoni: il tipo *_la sindaco_».

Comment: Si *la sindaco è grammaticalmente inaccettabile, penso lo sia anche *una sindaco.

Comment: Tuttavia, esistono parole che *veramente* non si declinano in genere come "adolescente" o "pianista". Sono queste anche oggetto della tua domanda? O fa riferimento soltanto a sostantivi maschili che si usano come nomi di professioni sovolte per donne?  (o anche sostantivi femminili che si usano come nomi di professioni sovolte per uomini come l'esempio posto da @DaG, o perfino nomi di animali  che possono avere due sessi ma sono sostantivi femminili come "scimmia", "tigre", ecc o maschili come "coccodrillo"...)

Comment: @DaG, l'esempio in effetti è un po' fuorviante. Forse è solo una questione di armonia, per esempio "la coniuge", "il coniuge", "un coniuge" o "una coniuge" non sono così tanto cacofonici.

Comment: Il discorso è molto semplice e non c'entra la cacofonia: [avvocato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avvocato) è un nome maschile, e quindi in base alle normali regole sulla concordanza eventuali articoli, aggettivi etc. che gli si riferiscono devono essere maschili. [segue]

Comment: Invece [pianista](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pianista) o [coniuge](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coniuge) sono sia maschili che femminili (o, volendo, il maschile e il femminile sono uguali, a differenza di avvocato/avvocata o attore/attrice) e quindi per le stesse regole della concordanza gli articoli, gli aggettivi etc. andranno al maschile o al femminile a seconda dei casi.

Comment: La questione è che l'articolo deve concordare con il **genere grammaticale** del sostantivo a cui si riferisce. Se questo sostantivo denota un essere vivente che ha un sesso, il genere grammaticale non sempre fa riferimento al sesso.

Comment: @DaG La casella per le risposte è più sotto :)

Comment: @DenisNardin: To', è vero! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parte che, come detto nella domanda, l'esempio è un po' infelice perché esistono sia “avvocata” che il deprecato “avvocatessa”, la questione non coinvolge problemi di cacofonia né il sesso della persona di cui si parla. Se il *genere grammaticale* di un nome è maschile, come “[avvocato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avvocato)”, in base alle normali regole sulla concordanza eventuali articoli, aggettivi etc. che gli si riferiscono devono essere maschili.

Quindi: “un avvocato famoso”, anche se parliamo (impropriamente) di una donna; “una spia famosa”, anche se è un uomo; “una tartaruga famosa”, indipendentemente dal sesso dell'animale.

Altro è il caso di nomi che, come “[pianista](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pianista)” o “[coniuge](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coniuge)”, sono sia maschili che femminili (o, per dirla in un altro modo, in cui il maschile e il femminile sono uguali, a differenza di avvocato/avvocata o attore/attrice) e quindi per le stesse regole della concordanza gli articoli, gli aggettivi etc. andranno al maschile o al femminile a seconda dei casi (Maurizio Pollini è un pianista famoso, mentre Martha Argerich è una pianista famosa).

Comment: Un'altro esempio è "promessa" col significato 8 del [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000593.jpg): "Era giovane noto  per il suo brillante ingegno e si poteva dire, insomma, una buona promessa" (De Pisis). Mi è venuto in mente leggendo [questa domanda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32673/problemas-de-concordancia).